# Why does DatePicker become unresponsive after a startEdit() in a custom JavaFX 11 TableCell?

Tags: javafx, datepicker, tableview, javafx-11

I have a `TableCell` that renders a date as a `DatePicker` when editing and as plain text when not editing.

When the `TableCell` is edited, the `DatePicker` should receive focus, its date should be selected and the cursor should be in the editor at the end of the date.  The `DatePicker`'s editor should then be ready to accept user input.

However, at the moment, when the cell is edited, the `DatePicker` gets focus but it (or its editor?) becomes unresponsive.  The date isn't selected and the cursor is nowhere in sight.  I can't click into the editor nor type anything into the editor.  The only thing that works is the button that shows the calendar popup.

Further, this *only happens the first time a `DatePicker` cell is edited in a given row*.  The next time the same cell in the same row is edited, it works fine.

It also works fine if I change `setContentDisplay()` to GRAPHIC_ONLY in `updateItem()` but I don't want to do that.

Below is a MVCE that demonstrates the issue.

To reproduce the behaviour, either double-click on a date cell or use the arrow keys to navigate to it and press F2.  The `DatePicker` will get focus but its date will not be selected and you won't be able to click into the `DatePicker`'s editor.

Now click anywhere off the date cell and then go back to the same cell in the same row and edit it a second time.  The date should then be selected and you should be able click or type into the editor.

What am I doing wrong?

I've Googled and found examples of `DatePicker`s in `TableView`s but all set content display to GRAPHIC_ONLY in `updateItem()`.  I've not been able to find any that use TEXT_ONLY except while editing.

I'm using the 11.0.2 versions of OpenJDK and OpenJFX running in Netbeans 11.0 on Windows 7.

```
package test016;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;
import javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter;

public class Test016 extends Application {

    private final ObservableList<DataModel> ol = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final TableView<DataModel> tv = new TableView();

    private Parent createContent() {

        loadDummyData();

        createTableViewColumns();

        tv.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        tv.setEditable(true);
        tv.setItems(ol);
        tv.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

        BorderPane content = new BorderPane();
        content.setCenter(tv);

        return content;
    }

    private void createTableViewColumns() {

        TableColumn<DataModel,String> col1 = new TableColumn<>("field1");
        TableColumn<DataModel,LocalDate> col2 = new TableColumn<>("field2");
        TableColumn<DataModel,String> col3 = new TableColumn<>("field3");

        col1.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().field1Property());
        col1.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<DataModel, String>forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter()));

        col2.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().field2Property());

        //**************************************************************
        //DatePicker TableCell begins here

        col2.setCellFactory(dp -> {

            DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();

            StringConverter<LocalDate> dateConverter = new StringConverter<LocalDate>() {
                @Override
                public String toString(LocalDate object) {
                    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/MM/yyyy");
                    return ( object == null ? "" : dateFormatter.format(object) );
                }

                @Override
                public LocalDate fromString(String string) {
                    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/MM/yyyy");
                    return string.isEmpty() ? null : LocalDate.parse(string, dateFormatter);
                }

            };

            datePicker.setConverter(dateConverter);
            datePicker.setEditable(true);
            datePicker.setDisable(false);

            TableCell<DataModel, LocalDate> cell = new TableCell<>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {

                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        //It works I set content display to GRAPHIC_ONLY
                        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                        //setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

                        setText(dateConverter.toString(item));
                        datePicker.setValue((LocalDate) item);
                        setGraphic(datePicker);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void startEdit() {

                    super.startEdit();

                    if ( getGraphic() != null && getGraphic() instanceof DatePicker ) {
                        //The problem only occurs when I set content display to TEXT_ONLY in updateItem().
                        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

                        //If I requestFocus() on the graphic, the DatePicker gets the focus but I cannot edit the date
                        //by clicking in the editor and typing something in.

                        //If I do NOT requestFocus() on the graphic, the cell containing the DatePicker gets focus but
                        //I can then click in the DatePicker's editor and type something in.  However, I cannot just
                        //start typing as the DatePicker doesn't have focus.

                        //This happens irrespective of whether I double-click on a cell to start the edit or
                        //navigate to the cell via the keyboard and then hit F2.

                        //The behaviour only appears the first time I edit a DatePicker in a given row.
                        //The second and subsequent edits for the same row work fine.

                        getGraphic().requestFocus();

                        //Requesting focus on the DatePicker's editor doesn't appear to have any effect, either with or 
                        //without first requesting focus on the graphic.
                        ( (DatePicker) getGraphic() ).getEditor().requestFocus();
                        ( (DatePicker) getGraphic() ).getEditor().selectAll();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void cancelEdit() {
                    super.cancelEdit();
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                }
            };

            return cell;

        });
        //**************************************************************

        col2.setPrefWidth(120);

        col3.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().field3Property());
        col3.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<DataModel, String>forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter()));

        tv.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(col1, col2, col3));

    }

    private void loadDummyData() {

        ol.add(new DataModel("1", LocalDate.parse("2001-01-01"), "x"));
        ol.add(new DataModel("2", LocalDate.parse("2001-01-01"), "x"));
        ol.add(new DataModel("3", LocalDate.parse("2001-01-01"), "x"));
        ol.add(new DataModel("4", LocalDate.parse("2001-01-01"), "x"));
        ol.add(new DataModel("5", LocalDate.parse("2001-01-01"), "x"));

    }

    private class DataModel {

        private final StringProperty field1;
        private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> field2;
        private final StringProperty field3;

        public DataModel(
            String field1,
            LocalDate field2,
            String field3
        ) {
            this.field1 = new SimpleStringProperty(field1);
            this.field2 = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(field2);
            this.field3 = new SimpleStringProperty(field3);
        }

        public String getField1() {return field1.get().trim();}
        public void setField1(String field1) {this.field1.set(field1);}
        public StringProperty field1Property() {return field1;}

        public LocalDate getField2() {return field2.get();}
        public void setField2(LocalDate field2) {this.field2.set(field2);}
        public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> field2Property() {return field2;}

        public String getField3() {return field3.get().trim();}
        public void setField3(String field3) {this.field3.set(field3);}
        public StringProperty field3Property() {return field3;}

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setTitle("OpenJFX11 - DatePicker in TableView");
        stage.setWidth(600D);
        stage.setHeight(600D);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Messing around with this it seems the call to `getGraphic().requestFocus()` and `getEditor().selectAll()` is causing the problem. I'm not sure why though. Calling `applyCss()` on the `DatePicker` before either `requestFocus()` or `selectAll()`, but after it's been set as the graphic, seems to help. However, the text selection only seems to work properly after the first time.

Comment: Thanks very much, Slaw. Using `applyCss()` as you suggested is a big help. The date is now editable and that's the most important thing. The unresponsive issue is a JFX11 (or maybe JFX9 or 10) thing, BTW. It didn't happen in JFX8. The `selectAll()` behaviour is the same, though, but is a minor issue compared to not being able to edit the date. I can work with that. Thanks again for your help. It's much appreciated as always.

Comment: Glad I could help at least somewhat. Also, note you can use [`LocalDateStringConverter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/util/converter/LocalDateStringConverter.html) rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Slaw's suggestion, a workaround for the unresponsiveness issue is to call `applyCss()` on the `DatePicker` *after* it's set as the graphic but *before* the `requestFocus()` and `selectAll()`.

While the `selectAll()` will still only take effect from the second edit of the same cell in the same row, the `DatePicker` will at least now respond to edits.

```
@Override
public void startEdit() {

    super.startEdit();

    if ( getGraphic() != null && getGraphic() instanceof DatePicker ) {

        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

        ( (DatePicker) getGraphic() ).applyCss(); //Workaround for the unresponsiveness issue.

        getGraphic().requestFocus();

        ( (DatePicker) getGraphic() ).getEditor().requestFocus();
        ( (DatePicker) getGraphic() ).getEditor().selectAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: If one [doesn't already exist](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/projects/JDK/issues/) you may wish to [submit a bug report](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/).

Comment: I couldn't find anything similar in the bug system but need to download JDK/JFX 12.0 first and test it with that. If it's still an issue, I'll submit a bug report. I've never logged a bug before, though. Scary thought. It's usually me who's made a coding bungle rather than a bug. lol!